# How to detect if a picture was taken with the front camera

Tags: android, camera, orientation

I am taking a picture using Intents.  Is there a way to tell from the image file whether the picture was taken with the front or rear camera?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ExifInterface`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) class to get data from a picture that is a .jpeg. There is a `MODEL` attribute that might have the camera's model. I do not know if it can tell you the position of the camera relative to the device.